# Categorical definition of null space and range of a linear map

Tags: category-theory, linear-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator\null{null}\DeclareMathOperator\range{range}$I just found these two theorems from the exercises in Axler's linear algebra book.

1. $\null T_1 = \null T_2$ iff there exists invertible $S$ on the codomain such that $T_1 = S T_2$.
2. $\range T_1 = \range T_2$ iff there exists invertible $S$ on the domain such that $T_1 = T_2 S$.

These feel very "category theory"-ish, but of course the book doesn't take that angle and doesn't say more. Are the morphism-only definitions of $\null$ and $\range$ useful in other categories? Do they have a different name?

Comment: To start you might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(category_theory) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(category_theory)

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You can look at Green's relations. They are usually defined for semigroups but work for categories. They generalize having the same kernel or image for a linear map.

Comment: You may want to edit your question because you have reversed the conditions. For example, the correct statement (as in the exercise in the book) is that null $T_1$ = null $T_2$ if and only if there exists invertible $S$ such that $T_1 = ST_2$.

Comment: @sheldon, ops, fixed.